# Typeerror: message.react() is not a function - using discord.js 14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Trying to upgrade to Discord 14 from 12, where I used to have commands that were invoked with ! - now trying slash commands. So I have this code:

```
const waitingMessage = await interaction.deferReply();
waitingMessage.react('');
```

But for the life of me, I can't get the bot to react to the interaction reply! I have to also do this for the poll command which posts an embed and adds emojis to it, but I get the same error:

```
const msg = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
msg.react('');
msg.react('');
```

./commands/scores.js:51
waitingMessage.react('');
^
TypeError: waitingMessage.react is not a function

Any help appreciated, not sure where I'm going wrong!

I have tried to set a var to await for the interaction.reply/deferReply and then use that var to react, as I have seen on other help posts. I have also tried to wrap the message.react() into a try catch block

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own problem for those wondering!!!

You need to include { fetchReply: true } as an option in the reply function

So the code would be

```
const waitingMessage = await interaction.deferReply( { fetchReply: true} );
waitingMessage.react('');
```

This works!